# Why is `pip` not found even though it is installed?

Tags: python, pip

Why is `pip` not found even though it is installed?

According to [the documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing/):

> Use the following command to check whether pip is installed:
>
> `C:\> py -m pip --version`

So, I checked that I have the pip installed.

Now I am trying to install the `matplotlib` and getting an error. Why? What am I missing?

```
C:\Users\thatisusername>py -m pip --version
pip 20.2.3 from C:\Users\thatisusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.9)

C:\Users\thatisusername>cd C:\Users\thatisusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip

C:\Users\thatisusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\pip>pip install matplotlib
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call pip as a module from the Python binary as well when installing a module.

`py -m pip install matplotlib`

Comment: @manymanymore no problem. Please mark as answer if this solved your problem.

Comment: I will be able to do it in 10 minutes only. SO policy :)